# PHP arrays: How to get the index where an element is

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

Here’s the following array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 14
        )
)
```

Then I have

```
$chosenNumber = 17
```

What I need to know is:

First) if 17 is in the array

Second) the key it has (in this case [0])

Third) the index it belongs (in this case [3])

I was going to use the in_array function to solve first step but it seems it only works for strings ..

Thanks a ton!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php and http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function arraySearch($array, $searchFor) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            if($value1 == $searchFor) {
                return array("index" => $key, "key" => $key1);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

print_r(arraySearch($your_array, 17));
```

Comment: I forgot to return false if there is no match. I've edited the function

Answer (score 1):

You should look using these :

```
in_array()
array_search()
```

Comment: I think you could improve this answer by including links to these functions in the php documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have used array_search function

```
$qkey=array_search(value,array);
```

Comment: returns false, and the element is there

Answer (score 0):

You use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
$index = array_search($chosenNumber, $myArray);
if($index){
    $element = $myArray[$index];
}else{
    // element not found
}
```

array_search returns false if the element was not found, the index of the element you were looking for otherwise.

**If a value is in the array multiple times, it only returns the key of the first match**. If you need all matches you need to use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the optional search_value parameter specified:

```
$indexes = array_keys($myArray, $chosenNumber);
```

This returns a (possibly empty) array of all indexes containing your search value.

Answer (score 0):

array_keys()

- Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

array_values()

- Return all the values of an array

array_key_exists()

- Checks if the given key or index exists in the array

in_array()

- Checks if a value exists in an array

You can find more information here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php